# How might old answers be moved to a more suitable (also old) question?

Tags: support, answers

I was trying to perform regular maintenance on a popular Python canonical, and encountered an answer that addressed a matter tangential to the actual question as asked. It turned out to be something that is a better fit for another major canonical that I know about. The author seems to agree with my analysis and is interested in moving the content.

Is there any provision (for example, that a moderator can do in response to a custom flag) for moving answers from one question post to another?

If not, what process can users follow to migrate their answers, that won't e.g. trip automated flags for duplicate content or otherwise raise suspicion?

Comment: There's this old feature request on MSE where giving moderators capability to move answers was proposed (Seems like it isn't implemented): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147896/can-moderators-be-allowed-to-move-answers-to-other-questions-piecemeal

Comment: Apparently there's a merge functionality now, because my new answer got surprisingly moved into an old question, and now it's missing the PyCharm context that the question I'd originally answered had... https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77751933/timeline

Comment: @AKX merging of questions is not a new functionality. This is a feature request for moving individual answers, rather than all answers to a question.

Comment: @VLAZ Okay, then I just hadn't come across it before! :)

Answer (score 8):

The only provision, at least to moderators, for moving answers is merging the questions (or migrating a question to a different site, but that moves the answers to the new site too). It may be possible for Community Managers to move an answer. It is, of course, possible for a developer with database access to move an answer.

##### The answer author can, effectively, move their answer

The normal way to move an answer is for the answer author to:

1. Delete the original answer.
2. Edit the original answer to get the Markdown source and copy the Markdown.
3. Create a new answer on the destination question using the Markdown from the original answer.

As I recall, I've done this myself a couple of times for my own answers when I belatedly realized I answered a duplicate question and felt my answer provided enough that wasn't already in an answer on the duplicate-target question to justify moving the answer, rather than just deleting.

The voting on the original answer is, of course, not moved to the new answer when it is manually moved.

If I recall correctly, I also either left a comment on the original answer or edited the original answer to mention that it had been moved and linked to the destination. I believe I left a note in the new answer on the destination question stating that I'd moved the answer and linked to the original.

Comment: To be clear: it's important that the deletion step comes first, yes? So as to avoid false alarms on duplicated-content-detection mechanisms? And are you implying that you undelete and edit the original answer after the move?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, deleting the original answer prevents an automatic flag from being raised for the duplicate answer when the new answer is posted (or edited). No, I was not implying that the original answer would be undeleted. The original answer should remain deleted. Answers can be edited while deleted. Only self-deleted questions can't be edited while deleted.

Comment: "If I recall correctly, I also either left a comment on the original answer or edited the original answer to mention that it had been moved and linked to the destination." - did you mean, on the original question? Or is such a comment intended for the 10k+ users? And what's the point of linking back?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant on the answer. The links were just to allow others who might see the answers to know what was going on, rather than potentially wondering. The original question was closed as a duplicate, so that gives anyone looking at the duplicate question a link to where to find answers.

Comment: Oh. That's a slightly different situation, I guess.